# Can't install mysqlclient-python on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am currently trying to install mysqlclient-python on ubuntu to use with Django and am having issues.

I am following this page: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

However, when I run 'pip install mysqlclient' I get the following error:

```
running install_lib

copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql_exceptions.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql_exceptions.py'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_robofish/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ynYYW0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_robofish/mysqlclient
Storing debug log for failure in /home/robofish/.pip/pip.log
```

I checked the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` directory, and it seems to be empty. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're trying to install mysqlclient in your global Python environment. I'd strongly recommend to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create an isolated Python environment.

If you still want to use the global environment, use `sudo pip install mysqlclient`.